# How do I set in the pom to not compile tests?

Tags: java, maven, testing, pom.xml

How do I set in the pom to not compile tests in Maven? I've tried:

```
<properties>
  <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>
```

but in that case, Maven compile the tests but don't run them. I need Maven don't compile my tests.

Comment: Maybe you can have a profile that points to the test source directory.  Otherwise, it's pointed to an empty one.

Comment: I need to not compile them because these tests call a webservice, parse it's classes and so. As the project is using Hudson for continuous integration, we need to compile and run these tests only when we explicity set them to do this.

Comment: @Rafael.  I think you break build portability when doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case a solution was to put tests in a profile (e.g. runTests), so when I want to run these tests, I add the parameter `-PrunTests`. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 8):

You have to define maven.test.skip to true.

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: This skips running them.  The OP wants to skip compilation

Comment: @user2863942 Quote from my link: _"If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin."_

Comment: -Dmaven.test.skip=true
Just for easy copy/pasting

Comment: You don't even need the "=true". By setting it it is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `surefire-plugin` for executing tests, you can configure it to skip them based on a naming pattern:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>%regex[.*[Cat|Dog].*Test.*]</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

This, however, requires the tests file names to conform to the desired pattern(s). At work we are using this approach, and have our tests end with `..UnitTest` or `..IntegrationTest`, so that we can easily turn each of them off by modifying the regex in the corresponding build profile.

Take a look at [Apache's documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) on the surefire plugin. You may find something more useful or better suited for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Configure maven-compiler-plugin to skip the compilation.
Once again, I do not recommend it.

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
  </properties>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: If I need to active the test compiling and running later, mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=false will work? Or I'll need another parameter?

Comment: @Rafael. I guess, you can make `maven.test.skip` to pull a double duty